# SharePoint 2013 JavaScript Client Object Model

Tags: javascript, php, forms, sharepoint

I am new to SharePoint and have just completed a public facing website. I want to add a contact form. However Microsoft's backend does not support PHP. I have been reading Microsofts documentation and examples on the client object model, but have not been able to produce a working example of what I am trying to do.

I want to have a contact form, then gather the data using JavaScript (I have already gotten this far). I then want to use the client object model to append the data onto an existing custom list in SharePoint. Is this possible on a public facing website?

Also I keep reading about a SP.js script, but have no idea where to find it, or where to include it. If anyone has any details on that it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

SP.js file is located on SharePoint server (C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\SP.js). The list of files to be included you can find [here](http://allthatjs.com/2012/04/17/using-sharepoint-csom-in-node-js/).

Also you can use [REST api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn198245.aspx) to achieve same goal.
In both cases you will need to authenticate to SharePoint. You can use OAuth for example.